# VMWare Workstation pro 15.5.6: is it safe to turn host (WIN10) to power off while VM is running?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM hosted on WIN10 by VMWare Workstation Pro 15.5.6.

Is it safe to have Win10 powered off (Manually of because UPS detected power failure) or should the running VM be powered off before the host OS?

Answer (score 0):

With VMware Workstation V16, if you shut down the Host, then VMware will shut down the guests as well. I am not sure what version of VMware started supporting this.

I think your version might, but certainly VMware V16 supports shutting down the Guest machines when the Host shuts down. You can try it to see.

A Guest machine cannot run when the Host shuts down and so must shut down as described above.

It is certainly safe for VMware V16 to shut Guests down with the Host shut down. You can just restart the Guest when the Host comes back up.

You can make a backup of your current machine on a USB drive and test very safely.

Comment: I don't want to try to see if it works. I want to be sure it is supported. Having it working once doesn't means it will always work in every condition.

Comment: Try updating VMware Workstation. I have tried all the above with V16 and it works fine (shutting down and suspending).  So it is worth upgrading. You can make a backup of your Ubuntu machine on a USB drive and shut down with your current version.